# Java System.getProperty("user.home") directory missing separator

Tags: java, windows-8, registry, home-directory

Whenever a user enters "~" as an argument, my program replaces it with System.getProperty("user.home").

After debugging, I see that this replaces "~" with "C:UsersSoulBeaver" and not "C:/Users/SoulBeaver".

Going through [previous questions about incorrect user.home folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693201/java-thinks-my-home-folder-is-the-c-drive), I found out that Java tries to fetch the path from

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\`

However, I'm using Windows 8 and there is seemingly nothing wrong:

[image]

At this point I'm assuming Java "eats" the backslash... so how do I prevent that from happening?

**Update**

Since the code was requested, here it is. This is taken from Allen Holub's [Solving Java's Configuration Problem](https://www.drdobbs.com/)

```
/**
 * For every enum element in the array, treat keys[i].name() as a key
 * and load the associated value from the following places (in order):
 *
 * <ol>
 *     <li>a -D command-line switch (in System properties)</li>
 *     <li>if no -D value found, an environment variable with the same name as the key</li>
 *     <li>if no environment found, the default stored in the Enum element itself</li>
 * </ol>
 *
 * That value must identify an existing directory in the file system, and a
 * File representing that location can be retrieved from {@link #directory(Enum)}.
 *
 * @param keys The values() array associated with the enum that's using this class.
 * @throws IllegalStateException if a given key doesn't have a value associated with it
 *          or if that value doesn't identify an existing directory.
 */
public LocationsSupport(T[] keys) throws IllegalStateException {
    StringBuilder logMessage = new StringBuilder("Loaded environment/-D properties:\n");

    try {
        for (T element : keys) {
            String how = "???";
            String key = element.name();

            String value;
            if ((value = System.getProperty(key)) != null)
                how = "from system property (-D)";
            else if ((value = System.getenv(key)) != null)
                how = "from environment";
            else if ((value = element.defaultValue()) != null)
                how = "from default. Mapped from: " + value;

            if (value != null)
                value = value.replaceAll("~", System.getProperty("user.home"));

            if (value == null || value.isEmpty())
                throw new IllegalStateException("Value for " +key +" cannot be null or empty.");

            File location = new File(value);

            createLocationIfNecessary(location, element.createIfNecessary());

            if (!location.isDirectory())
                throw new IllegalStateException("Location specified in "
                        +key
                        +" (" +asString(location) +") "
                        +"does not exist or is not a directory.");


            dictionary.put(key, location);

            logMessage.append("\t");
            logMessage.append(key);
            logMessage.append("=");
            logMessage.append(asString(location) );
            logMessage.append(" (");
            logMessage.append(how);
            logMessage.append(")\n");
        }
    } finally {
        if (log.getAllAppenders() instanceof NullEnumeration)
            System.err.println(logMessage);
        else
            log.info(logMessage);
    }
}
```

It's failing at trying to locate the default location for CONFIG:

```
public enum Places implements Locations {
    CONFIG ("~/config"),
    HOME   ("~"),
    TMP    ("~/tmp", true),

    TERM_STORE     ("~/tmp/indices/term_store/",     true),
    RESOURCE_STORE ("~/tmp/indices/resource_store/", true),
    PERSON_STORE   ("~/tmp/indices/person_store/",   true);
```

I am using **Java 1.7.0_13** and **IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.3**

Comment: Please show the code doing the replacement.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: I'm very sorry, I have updated the question with the relevant information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using regular expression based replacement.  In the replacement pattern for java regexes, the `'\'` character is special.  you need to pass the user home dir through `Matcher.quoteReplacement()` before using it as a replacement pattern (as covered in the [javadoc for the relevant method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)).

Comment: I ran this one line program in Windows 8 Java 7 `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));` and it wrote the backslashes. This answer is probably correct.

Comment: @jtahlborn:  I have updated the question with the code you requested. I hope that helps!

Comment: @SoulBeaver - and, seeing the code, my answer was spot on.  (p.s. next time i recommend including the code in the original question).

Answer (score 0):

may be following can give some info.

[Bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4787931)

[Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585534/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-home-directory-in-java)